# iPhone: span click doesn't work fine

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ios, iphone

I have problem when I want to touch on span 'arrow' to drop down second level of menu navigation.
When I touch on arrow, result is same as I touch on page (e.g Philosophie).
Arrow have css--> cursor:pointer;
On desktop version it works fine.

I use iPhone 5. If I touch the arrow and hold it for 1 second, then it works fine. But if I touch it just once, then it leads me to a page.

http://www.dodaj.rs/f/2n/ym/WnUC5W0/menu.jpg

```js
//First js for adding arrow

$(".menu-item-has-children").each(function() {
  $(this).prepend('<span onClick="" class="arrow"></span>');
});
$(".main-menu .menu li").first().addClass("first-page-item");


//Second js for dropwdown submenu

$('.arrow').on("click",function(e) {
  if ($(this).hasClass('opened')) {
    $(this).removeClass('opened');
    $(this).parent().find('.sub-menu').slideToggle();
  } else  {
    $(this).addClass('opened');
    $(this).parent().find('.sub-menu').slideToggle();
  }
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

```html
<ul class="menu">
  <li class="menu-item">
    <span onclick="" class="arrow opened"></span>
    <a href="#">Philosophie</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu" style="width: 208px; display: block;">
   <li class="menu-item">
        <a href="#">Über uns</a>
      </li>
     <li class="menu-item">
        <a href="#">Unser weg</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="menu-item"></li>
  <li class="menu-item"></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since that iPhone is a touch device, you should use touch events instead of click events.

So, you should:

1. Detect if the device is a mobile
2. Behave properly depending on the device type

Here is the code:

```
function goArrow(e) {
    if ($(this).hasClass('opened')) {
        $(this).removeClass('opened');
        $(this).parent().find('.sub-menu').slideToggle();
    } else  {
        $(this).addClass('opened');
        $(this).parent().find('.sub-menu').slideToggle();
    }
    e.stopPropagation();
}

var TOUCH = "ontouchstart" in window;

if (TOUCH) $('.arrow').on("touchstart", goArrow);
else $('.arrow').on("click", goArrow);
```